# FactoryGirl - reference another association factory

Tags: factory-bot

I have defined some different factories for my Plan model  as follows:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :plan do
    factory :free_plan do
      name "Free"
      description "Free Plan"
      price 0
      duration 999
      questions 5
    end

    factory :premium_plan do
      name "Premium"
      description "Premium Plan"
      duration 1
      price 3
      questions 1000
    end

    factory :premium_plus_plan do
      name "Premium Plus"
      description "Premium Plus Plan"
      duration 3
      price 7
      questions 1000
    end
  end
end
```

Plan model has many subscriptions. How is it possible to reference a specified plan factory from a Subscription factory (the below does snot work):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :subscription do
    user
    activated true

    factory :one_month_subscription do
      plan { premium_plan }
      start_date { Time.now }
      end_date { start_date.advance(months: 1)}
    end

    factory :three_months_subscription do
      plan { premium_plus_plan }
      start_date { Time.now }
      end_date { start_date.advance(months: 3)}
    end

    factory :expired_subscription do
      plan { premium_plus_plan }
      start_date { 2.years.ago }
      end_date { start_date.advance(year: 1) }
    end
  end
end
```

Any idea ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out myself, - you will have to use traits as follows:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :plan do
    trait :free_plan do
      name "Free"
      description "Free Plan"
      price 0
      duration 999
      questions 20
    end

    trait :premium_plan do
      name "Premium"
      description "Premium Plan"
      duration 1
      price 3
      questions 1000
    end

    trait :premium_plus_plan do
      name "Premium Plus"
      description "Premium Plus Plan"
      duration 3
      price 7
      questions 1000
    end
  end
end
```

And then call them in association like that:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :subscription do
    user
    activated true

    factory :one_month_subscription do
      association :plan, :premium_plan
      start_date { Time.now }
      end_date { start_date.advance(months: 1)}
    end

    factory :three_months_subscription do
      association :plan, :premium_plus_plan
      start_date { Time.now }
      end_date { start_date.advance(months: 3)}
    end

    factory :expired_subscription do
      association :plan, :premium_plus_plan
      start_date { 2.years.ago }
      end_date { start_date.advance(year: 1) }
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can easily create any subscription factory as follows (example in Rails console):

```
rails c --sandbox

[2] pry(main)> FactoryGirl.build(:one_month_subscription)
   (0.5ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  User Exists (2.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'haven@johnstonmoen.com' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "haven@johnstonmoen.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$Kt27fqceEJijx11WCdQWHOp8g2DJfAjIqhEi9B82KF.4AeU7536JW"], ["created_at", "2016-02-19 12:06:39.875910"], ["updated_at", "2016-02-19 12:06:39.875910"]]
   (0.3ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
   (0.5ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  Plan Exists (1.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "plans" WHERE LOWER("plans"."name") = LOWER('Premium') LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "plans" ("name", "description", "duration", "price", "questions", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Premium"], ["description", "Premium Plan"], ["duration", 1], ["price", "3.0"], ["questions", 1000], ["created_at", "2016-02-19 12:06:39.912615"], ["updated_at", "2016-02-19 12:06:39.912615"]]
   (0.4ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
=> #<Subscription:0x007f9da94ae360
 id: nil,
 user_id: 20,
 start_date: Fri, 19 Feb 2016,
 end_date: Sat, 19 Mar 2016,
 activated: true,
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil,
 express_token: nil,
 express_payer_id: nil,
 plan_id: 3>
[3] pry(main)> FactoryGirl.build(:three_months_subscription)
   (0.5ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  User Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'roberta@schowalterdubuque.ca' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "roberta@schowalterdubuque.ca"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$wsyEzEvm78IF.FLkRaOcPOyyaAx0Fi5eIWU4IyY/ENpzLBrqGXhRS"], ["created_at", "2016-02-19 12:07:24.774203"], ["updated_at", "2016-02-19 12:07:24.774203"]]
   (0.3ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
   (0.3ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  Plan Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "plans" WHERE LOWER("plans"."name") = LOWER('Premium Plus') LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "plans" ("name", "description", "duration", "price", "questions", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Premium Plus"], ["description", "Premium Plus Plan"], ["duration", 3], ["price", "7.0"], ["questions", 1000], ["created_at", "2016-02-19 12:07:24.780799"], ["updated_at", "2016-02-19 12:07:24.780799"]]
   (0.3ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
=> #<Subscription:0x007f9da93ec9e0
 id: nil,
 user_id: 21,
 start_date: Fri, 19 Feb 2016,
 end_date: Thu, 19 May 2016,
 activated: true,
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil,
 express_token: nil,
 express_payer_id: nil,
 plan_id: 4>
```

Hope this helps